# Get the Vaule from shell output

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, cut

I have below output from a shell command . How can i get only the "UUID" value which is "72b11d-c808-455d-b684-fdc77cb596" . Can some one help me ?

/dev/sdc1: UUID="72b11d-c808-455d-b684-fdc77cb596" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ac212435-01"

Desired output "72b11d-c808-455d-b684-fdc77cb596"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '/dev/sdc1: UUID="72b11d-c808-455d-b684-fdc77cb596" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ac212435-01"' | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1
"72b11d-c808-455d-b684-fdc77cb596"
```

Comment: If you like this answer mark it as accepted to let other users know your problem is solved. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer